# Uninstall Android Studio completely

Tags: 14.04, android, android-studio

I installed Android studio some time ago using the following suggested method:

> To set up Android Studio on Linux:
>
> Unpack the downloaded Tar file,
>   android-studio-ide--linux.zip, into an appropriate location
>   for your applications. To launch Android Studio, navigate to the
>   android-studio/bin/ directory in a terminal and execute studio.sh. You
>   may want to add android-studio/bin/ to your PATH environmental
>   variable so that you can start Android Studio from any directory.
>   Follow the links to install the SDK outside of the Android Studio
>   directories.

For whatever reason it has become corrupt and insists I must un-install and re-install. I can't for the life of me find how to un-install it however.

I didn't use `apt-get` so I can't do `apt-get remove`.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would suggest to check the installation directory for a readme or an uninstall script but in general: do what you did to install it in reverse order and delete everything you added as a setting or as a file on your system related to that installation.

---

Installations done with a tar file are mosttimes uninstalled with the `rm` command. You go to the directory where you went for this: "Unpack the downloaded Tar file, android-studio-ide--linux.zip, into an appropriate location for your applications" and `rm` the files and directories created here.

If you did "You may want to add `android-studio/bin/` to your PATH environmental" too you will need to undo this alteration by deleting `android-studio/bin/` from the file you added this PATH too.

Answer (score 97):

These are default locations as of Android Studio 1.0.2 and it is possible to change them by editing `..../android-studio/bin/idea.properties`.

1. Delete the android-studio folder;
2. Delete the sdk folder if it is in not inside the android-studio directory;
3. Delete `~/.AndroidStudio`, which contains `config` and `system`;
4. Delete `~/.android`;
5. Delete `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-android-studio.desktop`, if you created a shortcut using *Configure->Create Desktop Entry*.

**Note: Add on to step#5 above**
- Sometimes the icon launcher can be in one of the following locations to:

```
/usr/share/applications
/usr/local/share/applications
```

If your launcher file is in any of the first two directories, you will require root permissions to remove it.

**PPAs**
A deeper step of removing Android Studio completely from your Linux Distribution would also include the removal of PPAs related to Android Studio.

In Ubuntu 16.04,

- Go to **Software and Updates > Other Software**
- Scroll down the list and select to find the ones related to Android-studio
- Click remove and authenticate

This  helps  stopping  updates and the very annoying error message:
`The package has not been installed. I can't find the archive for it.`

Comment: actually there are multiple AndroidStudio directory. rm -rf ~/.AndroidStudio*

Comment: + /.gradle - may be rm from your home?

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko: If you only use Gradle with Android Studio I suppose it's safe to delete `~/.gradle` as well.

Comment: Adding to the answer
you might need to remove env variables 
`
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

`

Comment: in my case, there is another directory:
`/usr/local/android-studio`
Just a warning: be very careful when trying to remove this directory using the terminal. Avoid accidentally removing any other directory.

Comment: You mean that a simple uninstall is not the case. Sounds clumsy,.

Answer (score 20):

To re-configure you have to delete the following (hidden) folders:

`~/.android
~/.AndroidStudio`

To show these hidden folders in the file manager press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> when in your home directory (aka "~")

Answer (score 9):

Android Studio versions 4.0+ have built-in uninstall and replace functionality that uninstalls packages held in multiple locations by previous versions of Android Studio. Just run the installer of the latest Android Studio.

To uninstall the Android Studio snap package run the following command:

```
sudo snap remove android-studio
```

To uninstall a manually installed Android Studio .deb package search in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to check if there is a software source for a PPA for Android Studio, for example ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio. If so, remove this PPA by running a command of the form `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio`. The italicized text in the preceding command indicates that the name of the PPA can be changed if Android Studio was installed from a different PPA.

Then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt purge android-studio  
sudo apt autoremove
```

These commands will remove Android Studio, remove the dependencies of Android Studio that are no longer required by other packages and will also purge all related system configuration files.

Answer (score 7):

For people who installed Android Studio using Ubuntu make (`umake android`) you can simply uninstall it by running :

```
umake android --remove
```

After that just delete Android Studio's related folders in your `/home` folder :

```
rm -r ~/.AndroidStudio
rm -r ~/.android
```

Answer (score 1):

To "uninstall" this just delete the folder.
I think your problem is that you unzipped it to unfit folder - either you have no launch permissions for it, or it has space and rare symbols in path, or something. It should just work, you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed as root then your SDK location is `/root/Android`.

So you should delete that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Daniel and abu_bua's answer above, at least with android studio 2021 there are also config files that can be placed into ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3, per the install txt file inside the tarball. It also mentions that some data cache may be stored in ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Stacer" the software to remove complete android studio
so for install "Stacer" use below command:

- sudo apt install stacer
  Or:
- install stacer from store ubuntu[ubuntu store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THIeh.png)