# How to uninstall Android Studio from Ubuntu 14.04 by using Terminal?

Tags: 14.04, android-studio

I installed Android Studio from [here](https://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/) from terminal.How to uninstall it completely ?

There are previous questions in Ubuntu with same title but none explained    correct answer!(One question Explained to uninstall when downloaded tar file but not for terminal download)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: If it is manually installed type `which studio.sh` and it will show you where it is located. Then just remove it. `cd` to location, then `rm -rf android-studio`. Also there are hidden folders where the work is stored in your home. Remove those too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall Android Studio completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546723/uninstall-android-studio-completely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the `.deb` file then you can remove it using

`sudo dpkg --remove android-studio`

Or if you installed it via `apt-get` then you can remove it using

`sudo apt-get remove android-studio`

Have a read of [How can I uninstall software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If trying to uninstall android studio from ubuntu 18.04 the try using this

```
sudo apt-get remove android-studio
```

else if you manually installed from `.deb` file then this will help you out-

```
sudo dpkg --remove android-studio
```

Now in case if you installed android studio using snap ,then above commands will not work and show you following errors-

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove android-studio which isn't installed
```

You can try using `umake` to delete android studio-

```
umake android android-studio --remove
```

but in case it shows some error like this

```
ERROR: You can't remove Android Studio as it isn't installed
```

try using following command.

If you installed android studio using snap installation,then using this command
will uninstall android studio-

```
snap remove android-studio
```