# Uninstalling Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have gone through all of the previous threads, including all of the suggestions in the Completely Uninstall Android Studio thread, about uninstalling Android Studio and followed their directions and nothing helps. I installed Android Studio with the Standard installation but for a tutorial I'm following I need a Custom installation. I tried deleting the `/android-studio` folder along with the hidden `/.android` folder in my home directory and then re-extracting the folder from the original .zip file from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) however every time I re-run the studio.sh file from my terminal it immediately restarts as was without re-installing. I have tried

```
sudo apt-get remove android-studio
```

and it tells me it cannot find the package. I've also tried every possible answer I've found so far including installing ubuntu-make and ppa:purge and nothing works. I can't even search for android studio in my task manager bar. I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall Android Studio completely](http://askubuntu.com/questions/546723/uninstall-android-studio-completely)

Comment: It's not a duplicate simply because none of those solutions worked for me. If I should add this into that thread, no problem. But since those solutions solved the other user's issue, I thought I should start a new thread because of that.

Comment: I know your  pain. I already  have at least 4 different instances of androadstudio, which show up all over my startmenu, my ppackage manager and mdyfilesystem. At this point the easiest way to get rid of them might actually be a full factory reset.

Answer (score 5):

If you installed android studio using snap installation,then using this command

```
snap remove android-studio
```

will remove android studio

Answer (score 4):

For me (gnome-ubuntu 17.04) this got rid of all android-studio installations I could see:

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/androidstudio.desktop
sudo rm -rf /opt/androsudoid-studio/
rm -rf ~/.android/
rm -rf ~/.AndroidStudio2.1/
rm -rf ~/.AndroidStudio2.3/
rm -rf ~/Android
sudo rm -rf /opt/android-studio-ide-143.2790544-linux.zip
rm -rf ~/.gradle
```

Note: for you the build- and version numbers are probably different.

After that I could do a clean re-install and  finally got a clean, working android studio.

Answer (score 0):

sudo snap abort --last=install

In my Case it worked well

Comment: Android Studio was installed from studio.sh file.