# Uninstall android studio

Tags: android-studio

I updated android studio and it seems that something went wrong

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:96)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:93)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:154)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:128)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:191)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:128)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:318)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:140)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

I want to remove it completely from my laptop

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/546728/665251

Comment: @RobGoss not constructive. OP wants to remove android studio, not Ubuntu Studio.