# Can't launch Android Studio 3 and remove version 2 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, android, android-studio

Installed Android Studio 3 and can't launch. When ever launching android studio by search, only opening old version. Tried all the step mentioned in an [Old Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546723/uninstall-android-studio-completely) not worked.I need to remove old version and launch new version.

Comment: What steps exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by following these steps.

1. Go to `/home/[username]/`
2. Delete old android studio folders ***Android,.android,AndroidStudio 2.2***
3. open file explore with root permission `gksudo nautilus /usr/share/applications`
4. Delete old Android Studio launcher.
5. Launch new android studio. Now you got updated android studio